# Subprocess with " " gets interpreted wrong in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

This codeline gets inproperly interpeted because of the "". How to fix that? subprocess is imported.

```
subprocess.run("netsh wlan connect name="WLAN Name"", shell=True)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tru `'netsh wlan connect name="WLAN Name"'`

Comment: That's not a problem of subprocess, but rather of the string syntax in Python, I suggest.

Comment: Read about [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) in one of the first chapters of the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes here `subprocess.run('netsh wlan connect name="WLAN Name"', shell=True)`. The double quotes can also be used but you will have to use an escape with it.